# adding catextlayers to calayer in a background task

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, cashapelayer

I have a situation, which I do not understand.
I like to create CATextLayers in a background task and show them in my view, because it takes some time.

This works perfect without a background task. I can see the text immediately in my view "worldmapview"

```
@IBOutlet var worldmapview: Worldmapview! // This view is just an empty view.

    override func viewDidLoad(){

         view.addSubview(worldmapview);

    }
func addlayerandrefresh_direct(){
                var calayer=CALayer();
                var newtextlayer:CATextLayer=create_text_layer(0,y1: 0,width:1000,heigth:1000,text:"My Text ....",fontsize:5);

                    self.worldmapview.layer.addSublayer(newtextlayer)
                    //calayer.addSublayer(newtextlayer);
                    calayer.addSublayer(newtextlayer)
                    self.worldmapview.layer.addSublayer(calayer);
                    self.worldmapview.setNeedsDisplay();
  }
```

When doing this in a backgroundtask, the text does not appear in my view. Sometimes, not always, it appears after some seconds (10 for example).

```
func addlayerandrefresh_background(){
            let qualityOfServiceClass = QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND
            let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(qualityOfServiceClass, 0)

           dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, {

                var calayer=CALayer();
                var newtextlayer:CATextLayer=create_text_layer(0,y1: 0,width:1000,heigth:1000,text:"My Text ....",fontsize:5);
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{

                    self.worldmapview.layer.addSublayer(newtextlayer)
                    //calayer.addSublayer(newtextlayer);
                    calayer.addSublayer(newtextlayer)
                    self.worldmapview.layer.addSublayer(calayer);
                    self.worldmapview.setNeedsDisplay();
                })

            })
     }
    func create_text_layer(x1:CGFloat,y1:CGFloat,width:CGFloat,heigth:CGFloat,text:String,fontsize:CGFloat)  -> CATextLayer {
        let textLayer = CATextLayer()
        textLayer.frame = CGRectMake(x1, y1, width, heigth);
        textLayer.string = text
        let fontName: CFStringRef = "ArialMT"
        textLayer.font = CTFontCreateWithName(fontName, fontsize, nil)
        textLayer.fontSize=fontsize;
        textLayer.foregroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor().CGColor
        textLayer.wrapped = true
        textLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentLeft
        textLayer.contentsScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
        return textLayer;
    }
```

Does someone see, what is wrong ?
What is very confusing : The same doing with CAShapeLayer works in the background.

Comment: Please view my answer. I don't think this question needs bounty. It is pretty simple :)

Comment: Hi Fawad. It may be simple for you :-) , but I still don't know howto do. Can you help me more ? My Code can be just pasted to reproduce the problem. I would be happy to see the correction for getting this to work. Because from theory and reading the docs, I still don't get it.

Comment: You said "This works perfect without a background task", then why are you doing it in background? I have performed the task on main thread (using your code) and i am adding 100 subviews on the worldMapView and there is no delay. Please check if there is something else causing delay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like `setNeedDisplay` not cause sublayers redraw and we need call it on all layers we need, in this case it's newly added layer

```
func addlayerandrefresh_background(){
    let calayer = CALayer()
    calayer.frame = self.worldmapview.bounds

    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, {
        for var i = 0; i < 100 ; i+=10 {
            let newtextlayer:CATextLayer=self.create_text_layer(0, y1: CGFloat(i) ,width:200,heigth:200,text:"My Text ....",fontsize:5)
            calayer.addSublayer(newtextlayer)
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
            self.worldmapview.layer.addSublayer(calayer)
            for l in calayer.sublayers! {
                l.setNeedsDisplay()
            }
        })

    })
}
```

Comment: its the same problem. the calayer is a layer for all my CATextLayers. I have a lot. say 50. I did not define the sie of the calayer. I also did not for my layer for all CAShapelayers. To explain. I have 2 layers. one for texts and one for shapes.

Comment: Hi Sage. Thanks for helping ! I will try this tomorrow.

Comment: Hi Sage. I tried this, but it didn't work. I am coding in SWIFT 2.0 and I had to change the "0" to DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL. Is this right ? You can also take my code (Backgroundtask case) and reproduce the problem. It can be pasted into a viewcontroller.

Comment: @mcflysoft cheers, just played with your code and seems found solution, try call `newtextlayer.setNeedsDisplay()` after all methods.

Comment: @mcflysoft added better code sample, with explanation

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try this asap. I guess this is it. I will come back later.

Comment: Thank you very much. You got it ! All the best.

Comment: Hi Sage, Sorry for the late award. I just realized, that its not simple done by accepting the question. You helped me a lot. Have good time !

Comment: @mcflysoft thank you, award not the main goal for me I like solve curious problems like this one, but anyway thanks and good luck

Comment: Hi sage444 : I have a similar question, if you have time and like to look at it. I can't manage that :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33933611/uiimage-not-displayed-when-added-to-calayer-in-a-backgroundtask

Comment: @mcflysoft sorry mate, I'll be busy till Monday, but if you won't found any solution early you can ping me again;)

Answer (score 1):

All the changes on UI are performed on main thread. You cannot update User Interface on background thread. According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html)

> Work involving views, Core Animation, and many other UIKit classes
>   usually must occur on the app’s main thread. There are some exceptions
>   to this rule—for example, image-based manipulations can often occur on
>   background threads—but when in doubt, assume that work needs to happen
>   on the main thread.

Comment: can you explain what the difference between `performSelectorOnMainThread: ` and `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()...`

Comment: @sage444 Sorry,since CALayer is a Core Animation class, you cannot perform changes on it on background thread. I have updated the answer :)

Comment: I must apologize that I don't understand. I guess I am updating the GUI in the main thread. But your codesnippet, which obviously has gone was interesting. I tried it , but I got an error from the AppDelegate Class. "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException". Where is your code in the answer gone ?

Comment: I realized that the code I posted wont work. Therefore I removed it. Simple answer is that you cannot update Core Animation and UIKit classes on main thread. If you want the code snippet I can post it again.

Comment: I would be really happy to see the code snippet. You can simply take my code for a test. You will have all to reproduce the problem of the backgroundtask case.