# UIImage not displayed when added to CALayer in a backgroundtask

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, calayer

in my viewcontroller I have:

```
@IBOutlet var worldmapview: Worldmapview!


var eventLayer:CALayer=CALayer();
```

and some function:

```
func create_picture_layer(pathtopic:String) -> CALayer {
    let bm=getImage(pathtopic,fBitmapsizeSelected: 100)!;
    var calayer_for_picture=CALayer();
    calayer_for_picture.frame=CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100);
    calayer_for_picture.contents = bm.CGImage;
    return calayer_for_picture;
}

func createCircleShape(x:CGFloat,y:CGFloat, size:CGFloat) -> CAShapeLayer {

    var test2:UIBezierPath=UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(x - size/2, y - size/2, size, size));

    var shapelayer:CAShapeLayer=CAShapeLayer();
    shapelayer.backgroundColor=UIColor.clearColor().CGColor;
    //shapelayer.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300);
    shapelayer.fillColor=UIColor.darkGrayColor().CGColor;
    shapelayer.path=test2.CGPath;
    shapelayer.opaque=true

    return shapelayer;
}

func getImage(simagename: String, fBitmapsizeSelected:CGFloat) -> UIImage?{

    var sPathToImage:String=AppProperties.sharedInstance.sPicturePath + simagename;
    let checkValidation = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    if (!checkValidation.fileExistsAtPath(sPathToImage) || simagename.equals("")){
        // Path to unknown image
        let sunknownimagename:String = "na/na.jpa";
        sPathToImage=AppProperties.sharedInstance.sPicturePath + sunknownimagename;
    }

    let bm:UIImage=UIImage(contentsOfFile: sPathToImage)!;
    var bMapScaled:UIImage;
    if(!bm.isEqual(nil)){
        let newSize:CGSize=CGSizeMake(fBitmapsizeSelected, fBitmapsizeSelected);
        bMapScaled = bm.imageByScalingToSize(newSize,contentMode: UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill)!;
        return bMapScaled;
    }else{
        return nil;
    }
}
```

In my `viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) method` I try to show the image in worldmapview

the following code works fine without any background tasks. The image is shown immediately.

```
// works
let thepicturelayer=create_picture_layer("mypicpath")
eventLayer.addSublayer(thepicturelayer);
worldmapview.layer.addSublayer(eventLayer);
eventLayer.setNeedsDisplay();
```

in a background task and refreshing in the main task it doesn't work for me. Picture is not shown. After a while it appears, but not always.

```
// doesn't work

        let qualityOfServiceClass = QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND
        let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(qualityOfServiceClass, 0)

        dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, {
            // geht auch mit Eventlayer

            let thepicturelayer=self.create_picture_layer() // This Shape doesn't appear.
            let circleshapelayer=self.createCircleShape(200, y: 200, size: 20) // This shape appears immediatelly.

            self.eventLayer.addSublayer(thepicturelayer);
            self.eventLayer.addSublayer(circleshapelayer);


            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                    //assert(self.eventLayer.sublayers?.count > 0,"no layers in eventLayer !") // just added

                    self.worldmapview.layer.addSublayer(self.eventLayer);
                    //assert(self.worldmapview.layer.sublayers!.count > 0,"no layers in worldmapview!" ) // just added
                    let sublayers=self.eventLayer.sublayers;
                    if sublayers != nil {
                        for l in self.eventLayer.sublayers! {
                            l.setNeedsDisplay()
                        }
                    }
                    //self.updateWorldMapGUI();
                    self.worldmapview.layer.addSublayer(self.eventLayer);
                    //thepicturelayer.setNeedsDisplay();
                    //circleshapelayer.setNeedsDisplay();
                    self.eventLayer.setNeedsDisplay();

            })
        })
```

**Update**

I updated the code with a new CAShapelayer added the same way, which is displaying immediately. I do not understand the difference. The Picture is not shown, when created in a background task.

**UPDATE2**

I realized something confusing to me additionally:
Following Code without background task works as already described:

```
    let thepicturelayer=create_picture_layer()
    eventLayer.addSublayer(thepicturelayer);
    worldmapview.layer.addSublayer(eventLayer);
    eventLayer.setNeedsDisplay();
    //thepicturelayer.setNeedsDisplay(); // When adding this, the picture is not shown.
```

But activating the last line, the picture doesn't appear. Probably it has something to do with it ? It seems like the content of the calayer is gone ?

Comment: Can you confirm that `self.create_picture_layer("mypicpath")` is synchronous, and does not return immediately?

Comment: You are right. I updated the code. I wrote "its empty" and it runs into that situation. Do you have any hint how to solve this  ? I would like to prepare the layer in the background and refresh the view afterwords, when layer is added. How to do that ?

Comment: You should not modify UI in background thread.

Comment: Please look at the code. I am not doing this. The same way I can show CALayers without UIImages without any problem.

Comment: Anyone has a solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you are creating `CALayer` in the background, *and* adding that layer to the UI hierarchy in the background as well.

Would it be reasonable to think that all UI modifications are to happen in the `main` thread? If so, try this:

```
let qualityOfServiceClass = QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND
let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(qualityOfServiceClass, 0)

dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, {
    let thepicturelayer=self.create_picture_layer()

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
        self.eventLayer.addSublayer(thepicturelayer);
        assert(self.eventLayer.sublayers) // just added

        self.worldmapview.layer.addSublayer(self.eventLayer);
        assert(self.worldmapview.layer.sublayers) // just added

        self.worldmapview.setNeedsDisplay()
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, but it didn't work. I updated my Code. There we can see, that my new added circleshape appears immediatelly, but the pictureshape doesn't. Question is why ?

Comment: What is  behind `getImage`? Have you tried with an image present in an Assets Catalog?

Comment: I just updated the question with the code of getImage(). I did not try with asset Catalog. This also will be inpossible in my situation, because I don't know which pictures are there. They are in a specific folder on the device.

Comment: Did the one who upvoted the sample successfully tested the solution ?

Comment: I just realized something confusing, which I described in my question under UPDATE2. Probably it has something to do with it ?

Comment: I don't know about the +1. Did you notice I have a single `setNeedsDisplay` in my post? Do the `assert` fire?

Comment: Yes I realized. The Asserts I had to code differently. I hope that was fine : assert(self.eventLayer.sublayers?.count > 0,"no layers in eventLayer !"), because your original showed me errors. This assert was not fired. When I am understanding correct, this should test, if layers are there ?

Comment: Question: Did you try my code and it worked for you with the new solution ? Because it did not for me ?